# Bundle products in magento doesn't appear

Tags: magento, bundle, categories

I'm trying to configure in my magento show a bundle producto following this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product.

My bundle product is in stock. I've added two bundle items which are also in stock. I've add the bundle product to a category which is configured to show only products.

But my product doesn't appear. However other simple products in the same category appear correctly. Has anyone any idea of what I'm doing wrong or if I'm missing any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that status of the product is 'enabled' and visibility is 'catalog, search' and that you have selected a store on the 'websites' tab of the product if you are using multiple store config.

Comment: the status and visibility are ok, I can't see the website tab, there isn't one on the product configuration on Catalog menu. But, anyway, I have only a website, and I've created simple products on the same way and they appear.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same issue and it seems to be a design template issue. 
if visit your base url /catalog/product/view/id/{insert your product id.}

My guess is that you will get a page that shows no formatting but has the product. 
then if you change the bundled product design to default you will see updated formatting.. This will get you closer to solving the mystery